# Fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 boot very slow

Tags: boot, ssd

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on a 256 GB Samsung SSD.
I noticed a very slow boot process, specially if compared with my other OS (Ubuntu 12.04) installed in a separate SSD.

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.829s (kernel) + 34.163s (userspace) = 38.992s
```

Any idea why?

My system is Acer Aspire 7750G,
CPU Intel Core i5 2410M 2.3Ghz,
Ram 8 GB,
SSD 256 GB Samsung,
AMD Radeon HD 6650M 1 GB VRAM.

Once logged in, the system is quite fast.

Comment: 1st boot after a system update is noticeably slower then normal ... are you seeing this slowness after another boot up ?

Comment: Are your disk partitions aligned? Use `sudo fdisk -l` for a quick check, and `sudo parted` align-check for a more accurate check. Do you have the latest firmware in the Samsung SSD?

Comment: I reboot many times: once after the installation, then after some updates, then again... And today I got the same boot time.

The output of sudo fdisk -l is too long (more than 3.000 char). How can I attach a log file ?

Comment: Here you can find the sudo fdisk -l output:

http://pastebin.com/kMrdLZHy

Comment: fdisk doesn't show any partition alignment problem. Always start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Did you intentionally format your SSD with MBR instead of GPT?

Comment: @heynnema: I just left default installation parameters; I only chose the disk where to install, which was an Windws 7 system. Is that the problem, maybe?

Comment: @heynnema: my notebook does not support UEFI so, if I'm not wrong, MBR is ok.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.

Comment: @heynnema: googling around I found the command

systemd-analyze blame

which gives the following output http://pastebin.com/c8btS3Lp

It looks like plymouth-quit-wait.service takes more than 21s. Is it right?

Comment: You could edit /etc/default/grub (`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`),  change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and temporarily remove quiet splash (leave only ""), save and quit gedit, then `sudo update-grub`, `reboot`, and watch if 1)the startup is any faster, and 2)the text output shows you where it's taking so long. Put quiet splash back later.

Comment: ps: you could also `more /var/log/syslog` and look around the time of the last boot, and see if you can find out what it was doing during boot.

Comment: ps: you could also `dmesg | more` and see exactly what happened during the last boot.

Comment: @heynnema: Unfortunately, boot is still slow.

systemd-analize, gives me:
Startup finished in 11.765s (kernel) + 27.483s (userspace) = 39.249s

systemd-analyze blame
gives the following output http://pastebin.com/YvnTwynN

systemd-analize critical-chain
gives the following http://pastebin.com/LydZrkKE

....and I find very hard to understand what is taking so much time in the dmesg | more here   http://pastebin.com/mtrLt3gw

Comment: You're having disk problems. **Did you check for a Samsung firmware update that I suggested earlier?** Start the `Disks` app, select the disk in the left pane, then go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART data & tests` and review the data and run the tests.

Comment: ps: Do you have system BIOS firmware 1.21?

Comment: @heynnema: sorry, I completely missed you suggestion about the SSD firmware.   I asked the Samsung support I they told me there is no firmware update for my Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA 250GB (EMT41B6Q).   I also run the disk benchmark: you can see the results here https://postimg.org/image/65oftyvqv/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52021/discussion-between-heynnema-and-user59114).

Comment: @heynnema: yes my BIOS firmware is 1.21     *-firmware       description: BIOS
          vendor: Acer
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.21
          date: 08/09/2012
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 2496KiB